# Forge Disconnected Workflows not working in iphone

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, 3d-model

Has anyone tried this in iphone, https://forge-disconnected.autodesk.io/

It works fine on windows, mac and android, but on iphone it seems to be stuck at this screen,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTor.png)

Also, we have already enabled javascript from settings in the phone.
Is it something from my end or it does not work on iphone?

Tried loading the url directly in safari but it does not load the list of the models at the top left corner and nor does any model load up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the heads up. There was a problem with the [window.storage.estimate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/estimate) method which is no longer supported on iOS. We've [updated](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-disconnected/commit/c70e28ebb536ba0a50ded50542a4935c075e6002) the source code, and the live demo should now work on iOS devices again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Petr, the models have started loading on the iphone now, at least in online mode. But when offline it still shows an error asking are you offline

Comment: Hrmm you're right. The demo is a bit outdated, and it's using the latest version of the viewer which now loads the model assets from different URLs (other than those cached by the service worker). We'll need to do a general refresh of that code sample.

Comment: While we're addressing this issue, please consider using the [sample/disconnected-workflow](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs/tree/sample/disconnected-workflow) branch of https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-simple-viewer-nodejs for reference. I've recently created this branch to modify the Simple Viewer sample to support offline caching as well. And this sample is caching the new URLs required by the viewer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Petr we will give this branch a try. Thank you for your quick support

Comment: tried the branch you mentioned, again, it works in offline in android and windows, but on ios, it does say cache successful when you cache a model, but when trying to open in offline mode, it still gives an error saying network problem

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, the updated demo was working on my iPhone. Could it be that you're still looking at the old app due to the service worker caching? If you have a MacBook, could you connect your iOS device to it via USB-C, debug the iOS browser via Safari, and see if there's any errors?